# How do I modify the following Regular Expression to also match some other specific strings?

Tags: javascript, regex

I know this is a really dumb question, but I've literally been trying to solve this on my own for the last 5 days and I don't seem to be close to any kind of solution yet.

So here's the problem:

```
var p= /\+?\d{1,4}?[-.\s]?\(?\d{1,3}?\)?[-.\s]?\d{1,4}[-.\s]?\d{1,4}[-.\s]?\d{1,9}/g;
console.log(document.body.innerText.match(p));
```

The variable "p" contains a RegEx pattern that should match any telephone number. Especially important to me are the german telephone number formats. I also have some customers that write their numbers like this though: "00000 / 00000-00" (0 should match any digit. I'm just using 0 for an example here.)

So how would I modify the pattern above to also match these weird formats that include "/" and "-" here?

Thank you for taking the time to help me.

Comment: Would it be simpler to just capture 5-20 digits separated by a dash, period, or whitespace which is not a newline? `\d(?:(?![\r\n])[-.\s]?\d){4,19}/g`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

`/\+?\d{1,4}?[-.\s]?\(?\d{1,3}?\)?[-.\s]?\d{1,4}[-.\s]?(\s?\/\s?)?\d{1,4}[-.\s]?\d{1,9}[-.\s]?(\d{1,9})?/g`

You should use sites like https://regex101.com/ for developing regex code. They assist you with a bunch of stuff.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. I'll try regex101. But your proposed solution already helped me a lot. :D